# How to print tweet's hyperlink in TwitterOAuth

Tags: php, twitter-oauth

I am using TwitterOAuth to tweet from my own PHP code. everything is working fine. I just want to know how can I echo tweet's hyperlink that user has just tweeted through my PHP app. Here is my code that I am using for tweet posting:

```
<?php

//LOADING LIBRARY
require "twitteroauth/autoload.php";
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;


$consumer_key = '';
$consumer_secret = '';
$access_token = "";
$access_token_secret = "";


$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $access_token, $access_token_secret);
$content = $connection->get("account/verify_credentials");

$statues = $connection->post("statuses/update", array("status" => "hello world"));

if ($connection->getLastHttpCode() == 200) {
    echo 'Tweet posted succesfully';

} else {
    echo 'Handle error case';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response that Twitter `statuses/update` gives out after you post a Tweet is documented [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update).
For me, it looks something like this -

```
Array
(
    [id_str] => 662128569695383552
    ...
    [user] => stdClass Object
        (
            [screen_name] => couchthomas
            ...
```

The `id_str` and the `screen_name` can be used to build the Tweet url.

```
https://twitter.com/<screen_name>/status/<id_str>
```

So, if you get a response like the one above, it would look something like this -

```
$id_str = $statues["id_str"];
$screen_name = $statues["user"]->screen_name;
$tweet_url = "https://twitter.com/$screen_name/status/$id_str";
```

Try `var_dump`ing the `$statues` variable and build it accordingly.

**EDIT**
Now that I've the OP  output, clarifying this answer.
The output looks like this -

```
object(stdClass)#7 (23) { 
    ["created_at"]=> string(30) "Thu Nov 05 12:17:43 +0000 2015" 
    ["id"]=> int(662242385318014977) 
    ["id_str"]=> string(18) "662242385318014977" 
    ...
    ["user"]=> object(stdClass)#22 (40) 
        { 
            ...
            ["name"]=> string(8) "Eggs Lab" 
            ["screen_name"]=> string(7) "EggsLab"
```

So, accordingly, you can fetch the `id_str` of the tweet(which is a direct key `statues`) and the user's `screen_name`(which is a nested in the obj `user` inside `$statues`) by -

```
$id_str = $statues->id_str;
$screen_name = $statues->user->screen_name;
```

and create the tweet url as explained above.

Comment: Great, Glad it helped :)

Comment: But there is one problem. I can't get screen_name most of things don't appear.

Comment: @HafizAbdullahMajid Hmmm... not sure why(screen_name will always be returned by Twitter). Could be an array/object thing. Try `$statues["user"]["screen_name"];`. If that doesn't  work, can you paste the output of `var_dump($statues)` here?

Comment: Sorry the output is too long here you can see [here.](http://eggslab.net/r/t.php)
also I use $statues->id_str to get id_str value but for screen_name it shows nothing

Comment: Ah... its not `$statues->screen_name`. It's `$statues->user->screen_name`. See, it's visible in the output as - `["screen_name"]=> string(7) "EggsLab" `